# Creating vector of vectors from text file

Tags: c++, text, vector

I have to create a vector of vectors from a text file. The values in question are integers.

The values are a fixed 3 columns with varying rows. However, I don't believe this is causing my issues. The main issue I think I'm having is that the values from the text file aren't being put into the vector of vectors. The relevant code is as follows:

```
ifstream infile("material_properties.txt");
if (!infile)
{
    cout << "File material_properties.txt not found." << endl;
    return -1;
}

int lines = 0;
string line;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    ++lines;
}

vector< vector<int> > properties(lines,vector<int>(3));

while (getline(infile,line)) {

    for(int i=0; i < lines; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            infile  >> properties[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

I'm very new to coding and very confused.

Comment: 0,1,2,3, where's the last one gonna be?

Comment: You are counting wrong `for (int j=0; j<4; j++)` as @MartinJames is mentioning.

Comment: Wow. I don't know how I messed that one up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off

```
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    ++lines;
}
```

Is going to read in the file until it reaches the end of the file.  Then when you go to read from the file again you are already at the end so nothing will be read.  Instead of read in from the file to find the file size you can just read from the file and input the values into the vector.  The vector will grow as you add data to it automatically.

```
ifstream infile("material_properties.txt");
vector< vector<int> > properties;
vector<int> row(3);
while (infile >> row[0] >> row[1] >> row[2])
{
    properties.push_back(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling my code was much more complicated than needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewind your ifstream, add:

```
infile.seekg(0);
```

before your second `while (getline(infile,line)) {`

This is because when you read a file, an internal pointer to the current file position is incremented. It incremented until end of file in first getline loop, so in second you need to rewind it.

Your second bug is that in;

```
vector< vector<int> > properties(lines,vector<int>(3));
```

you create vector of three elements in your vector of vector, but in the read loop you add four elements from your file. You should change it to `vector<int>(4)`.

Third issue, is your way of parsing file. In your second loop you read file line by line, which indicates you want to parse it, but your code is actually wrong:

```
int i = 0;
while (getline(infile,line)) {
    // This actually makes no sense, you have read one line 
    //  which you should parse and put results into properties vector. 
    //for(int i=0; i < lines; i++){
    //    for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
    //        infile  >> properties[i][j];
    //    }
    //}    

    // parsing would look like this (depends on your input file):
    std::istringstream in(line);
    in >> properties[i][0] >> properties[i][1] >> properties[i][2];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I added this, however when I do cout << properties[0][0] << endl; it prints a value of 0 to the console

Comment: Thats a third issue in your code, but I dont know your input file - once you read a line from it you should parse it - but you are actually reading more data from your file.